# Unable to output to lpt1: from cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line, parallel-port, dot-matrix-printer

I am running Windows 7 32-bit on an old laptop with an onboard parallel port. I have an Okidata Microline 320 printer connected to that port; the printer has been tested to work fine when printing from a Winterm in emulation mode.

The ML320 driver that ships with W7 is outputting garbage when I attempt to print (I have tried from Notepad and from Word 2010). In an effort to troubleshoot this, I tried running various commands from `cmd`, such as `echo hello > lpt1` and `echo.>lpt1`, neither of which did anything.

If I type simply `lpt1`, the "choose a program to open this file" dialog comes up, but telling it to open with Notepad does nothing. `print lpt1` returns the expected `Can't find file lpt1` to stdout.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the printer seems to have corrected this. I feel silly now.